# rendering different screen based on input by the user React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello fellow programmers, i wanted to ask how can i achieve different screen rendering based on input by the user. I have done it in one way but i want to know is there any better way to do?

Attached is the link to [snack on expo](https://snack.expo.io/@daniyal_shaikh/snackscr). You can run it and see the code of how i have done it.

If there are better alternates, please let me know.

Thankyou.

**please dont mark the question as duplicate before going throught it.**

Comment: Why not use something like react-navigation ?

Answer (score 0):

For better choice you can using `react-navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ This package work in Expo

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted looks mostly like something I would use conditional rendering techniques for like the && syntax

See here for more guidance:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

If your pages are dramatically different though (not just options flipping on and off) then I would recommend react navigation as giri commented.